# What is the limit for this function?

Tags: limits

Is the limit for this function exist?

$\lim_{ x\to 3}$ for $f(x)=|2x-4|$

I think the limit for this function is $2$.

Is my answer correct or not? Because my teacher said there is no limit for this function. So I am confused

Comment: I dont see any reason why your answer should be wrong. The function is continous and the limit is well defined.

Comment: @MrYouMath that means my answer is correct, right?

Comment: Yes, your answer is correct.

Answer (score 3):

\begin{align}
  \lim_{x\to 3} |2x-4| &= \left|\lim_{x \to 3}(2x-4)\right|\\[0.3cm]
    &= \left|2(3)-4\right|\\[0.3cm]
    &= 2
\end{align}

We can push the limit into the absolute value because the absolute value function is continuous and it's ok to push limits into continuous functions.

So $|2x-4|$ does have a limit which exists as $x \to 3$.

A related statement that's similar to what you were told (except for the fact that this related statement is true) is that $|2x-4|$ doesn't have a derivative at $x=2$.  Note that that's 2 and not 3.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that $|2x-4|=2x-4$ when $x\ge2$ and then
$$\lim_{x\to3}|2x-4|=\lim_{x\to3}(2x-4)=2(3)-4=2$$